# Error en Break y Continue

Tags: javascript

[image: Error en Break y Continue]
No entiendo porqué me sale error en Break y Continue si creo que declaré en arreglo mi variable por favor denme una mano con esto

Comment: ¿Seguro que el break y continue va ahí? ¿Qué quieres que suceda cuando la condición `i === 5` ocurra?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y 1: muestra el código _como texto, con formato_, 2. qué mensaje de error aparece al colocar el mouse encima de `break` y `continue`. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Te están sobrando los punto y coma (`;`) que están después de los for.

```
for (let i=0;i<numeros.length;i++) ; // <- Este no va
{
    ...
}
```

Si pones el mouse sobre la palabra marcada en rojo, te da una ayuda el editor.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.